# Would like to enter integers such as "01" and "07" but an "invalid literal" error comes up. Overall program is an RLE compressor

Tags: python, error-handling, radix

I am doing an assignment for school in which I have to compress data using RLE.

When I type in something such as `2t7e` it works perfectly, but when I try to input it as `02t07e` it comes up with the error

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: y
```

My code:

```py
def decode(mstr):
    rle = ''

    if mstr != '':
        for i in range(0,len(mstr),2):
            number = int(mstr[i])
            character = mstr[i+1]
            rle = rle + character*number
            list1.append(rle)

    return rle



for i in range (0,linesOfRLE):                                                               
    text=input("Please enter the string to encode")
    x = decode(text)
    print(list1)
```

I would like to input something like `02t04a10b` and get
`ttaaaabbbbbbbbbb`.

Comment: can you use regex?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

> ```
> for i in range(0,len(mstr),2):
> ```

You are iterating every 2nd char of your input and take it as number to deencode. If you have multiple digit rle amounts this does not work: you need to refine your code to handle that.

For `'02t04a10b'`:

- it tries to create `0` times `'2'`
- then tries to convert `'t'` to `int` => invalid literal

I would suggest disallowing `01` `02` numbers, if you need to also decode `'14a'` into `'aaaaaaaaaaaaaa'` or  `'5142'`  to `'111112222'` you need to give your logic even more "smarts".

---

If you can restrict your encoding to`A-Za-z` I suggest using [.isdigit()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) to read as long from your string as you get digits, then multiply the next one with it, then continue.

See [google for `python run lenght  site:stackoverflow.com`](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHBF_deDE771DE771&ei=DiP1XMOBPMWcsAfs7qiIBw&q=python+run+lenght++site%3Astackoverflow.com&oq=python+run+lenght++site%3Astackoverflow.com&gs_l=psy-ab.3...4560.4560..5170...0.0..0.72.72.1......0....1..gws-wiz.yvKgReFl2h8) for inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this line

```
number = int(mstr[i])
```

since when i = 2 then mstr[2] will be 't', and you're trying to convert the letter 't' to int, which is not possible.

**Use this**

```
def decode(mstr):
    rle = ''
    j = 0
    if mstr != '':
        for i in range(0, len(mstr)):
            if mstr[i].isalpha():
                number = int(mstr[j:i])
                character = mstr[i]
                rle += character * number
                list1.append(rle)
                j = i + 1
    return rle
```

Answer (score 0):

**If you can use [RegEx](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html), you can have a clean and readable code:**

```
import re


def decode(mstr):

    reg_res = re.findall("\d*\w", text)
    res = ''.join([x[-1]*int(x[0:-1]) for x in reg_res])

    return res

text = "02t04a10b"

print(decode(text))
```

**Output:**

> `ttaaaabbbbbbbbbb`

**Line explanation:**

> `reg_res = re.findall("\d*\w", text)`

In this line we find all the number/letter pairs. In the RegEx context, `\d*` means "all the digit" and `\w` means "a letter": we're looking for all the groups formed by *n* digits followed by a letter

> `res = ''.join([x[-1]*int(x[0:-1]) for x in reg_res])`

In this line, for each couple (`for x in reg_res`), we take the last char `x[-1]` (we know is our letter) and multiply it for the previous number `int(x[0:-1)`. we join all the results in a single string without spaces with `''.join(list)`

---

**If you can't use RegEx**:

```
def decode(mstr):
    res = []
    num = ''

    for l in mstr:

        if l.isdigit():
            num += l
        else:
            res.append(l*int(num))
            num = ''

    return ''.join(res)

text = "02t04a10b"
print(decode(text))
```

**Output:**

> `ttaaaabbbbbbbbbb`

**Line explanation:**

```
if l.isdigit():
    num += l
else:
    res.append(l*int(num))
    num = ''
```

for each `char` in `mstr`, if `char` is a digit, add `char` to the number holder, else multiply char for the number holder and append the result